# Macro is running but gives an error when switching between workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I have an time running workbook in excel which tracks time with an start pauze and finshed button.
when this time is running it and i open another workbook or switch between workbooks it will give an error, but i can't find out why

it tells me the subscript is out of reach
it looks like if open another sheet its looking for

```
Sub StartTimeCobalt()
If Range("c13").Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please fill in Machine quantity"
  End If
PreviousTimerValue = Sheets("CalculationsCobalt").Range("a1").Value
t = Time
Call ExcelStopWatchCobalt
End Sub

Private Sub ExcelStopWatchCobalt()
If Range("c13").Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please fill in Machine quantity"
  End If
Sheets("CalculationsCobalt").Range("a1").Value = Format(Time - t + PreviousTimerValue, "hh:mm:ss")
NextTick = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
If Sheets("CalculationsCobalt").Range("a1").Value > Sheets("CalculationsCobalt").Range("B3") And Sheets("CalculationsCobalt").Range("a1").Value <= Sheets("CalculationsCobalt").Range("B4") Then
    With StopWatch.Shapes("TimeBox")
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    End With
    
Else
    If Sheets("CalculationsCobalt").Range("a1").Value > Sheets("CalculationsCobalt").Range("B4") And Sheets("CalculationsCobalt").Range("a1").Value <= Sheets("CalculationsCobalt").Range("B5") Then
    With StopWatch.Shapes("TimeBox")
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    End With
    
Else
    If Sheets("CalculationsCobalt").Range("a1").Value > Sheets("CalculationsCobalt").Range("B5") Then
    With StopWatch.Shapes("TimeBox")
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End With
End If
End If
End If


Application.OnTime NextTick, "ExcelStopWatchCobalt"
End Sub

Sub StopClockCobalt()
On Error Resume Next
Application.OnTime earliesttime:=NextTick, procedure:="ExcelStopWatchcobalt", schedule:=False
End Sub
Sub Reset1Cobalt()
On Error Resume Next

With StopWatch.Shapes("TimeBox")
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End With


If Sheets("Cobalt").Range("b27") = "" And Sheets("CalculationsCobalt").Range("a1").Value > 0 Then
    Sheets("Cobalt").Range("b27").Value = 1
    Sheets("Cobalt").Range("b27").Offset(0, 1).Value = Sheets("CalculationsCobalt").Range("a1").Value
Else:
    Sheets("Cobalt").Range("F2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = Sheets("Cobalt").Range("F2").End(xlDown).Value + 1
    Sheets("Cobalt").Range("F2").Offset(0, 1).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = Sheets("CalculationsCobalt").Range("a1").Value
End If
Application.OnTime earliesttime:=NextTick, procedure:="ExcelStopWatchCobalt", schedule:=False
Sheets("CalculationsCobalt").Range("A1").Value = 0
End Sub

Sub Reset2Cobalt()
Range("C10").Value = Now()
On Error Resume Next

With StopWatch.Shapes("TimeBox")
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End With


If Sheets("Cobalt").Range("f27") = "" And Sheets("CalculationsCobalt").Range("a1").Value > 0 Then
    Sheets("Cobalt").Range("f27").Value = 1
    Sheets("Cobalt").Range("f27").Offset(0, 1).Value = Sheets("CalculationsCobalt").Range("a1").Value
Else:
    Sheets("Cobalt").Range("F2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = Sheets("Cobalt").Range("F2").End(xlDown).Value + 1
    Sheets("Cobalt").Range("F2").Offset(0, 1).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = Sheets("CalculationsCobalt").Range("a1").Value
End If
Application.OnTime earliesttime:=NextTick, procedure:="ExcelStopWatchCobalt", schedule:=False
Sheets("CalculationsCobalt").Range("A1").Value = 0

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Range("b31:o31").Select
 Selection.Copy
 ChDir "\Time Sheet"
 Workbooks.Open filename:="\Time Sheet\Data.xlsx"
 Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
 Sheets("Data").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 ActiveWorkbook.Save
 ActiveWindow.Close
 Range("B8").Select
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 'Updateby Extendoffice
Range("b27", "c27").ClearContents
Range("c8", "c13").ClearContents
Range("f27", "g27").ClearContents
Range("j27", "k27").ClearContents
Range("n27", "o27").ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: Every instance of `Sheets` should be preceded with the appropriate workbook reference.

Comment: You need to fully qualify your range and worksheet, `Range` and 'Sheet` without any reference to worksheet and workbook assume it is the activeworkbook/activesheet

Comment: then i have next issue, the workbook name is an dynamic one.
the name of the workbook is in cell C11 +xlsm
any idea how i can use that as an reference?